# How to set a listview item and have it coloured (with the original selection colour)

Tags: c#, forms, listview, listviewitem

I'm trying to get any items set to `focused/selected/"blue coloured".`

But it does not work. I can only the `LightSteelBlue` doing the job, but that's not what I actually want :(

I want the standard form `selection appareance`, as if I were to select any apps manually (multi select works by the way).

Thanks for your help

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Control)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                item.Checked = true;
                item.Focused = true;
                item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you  tried "item.IsSelected = true"?

Comment: you need to check if the `item.IsSelected == true` inside the foreach loop also you need to change the `item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;`

Comment: BrunoJoaquim IsSelected does not have a setter.
@MethodMan well is that the only way? colouring the item

Answer (score 0):

Select the items inside of your loop with item.Selected = true;

I suggest setting HideSelection to false so that your items are still highlighted when the listview loses focus.

**Example Code**

*Just a minor correction*

```
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                item.Checked = true;
                item.Selected = true;
            }
```

Underneath InitializeComponent(), put the following:

```
            listview1.HideSelection = false;
```